# Displacement and Pressure Wave

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, displacement

In the relation between displacement and pressure wave in sound how can there be maximum pressure when there is zero displacement of a particle,doesn't the exact opposite happen in a compression wave when the particles are at the maximum displacement and pressure is the highest?

Comment: Duplicate - [Pressure variation in a sound wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/499801/104696)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pressure variation in a sound wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/499801/)