# Amplitude of periodic waves on a sine curve

Tags: waves

In a transverse wave, as shown in this figure:

[image: transverse wave on a spring represented by spring itself (a transverse wave on a represented on sine curve (b)]

the amplitude is simply measured as the distance between equilibrium (zero displacement) and maximum displacement, as is also shown on the sine wave representation.

I am quite confused about how this works for longitudinal waves. For a density wave traveling on a spring, as shown in the figure:

[image: longitudinal wave on a spring represented by spring itself (a longitudinal wave on a represented on sine curve (b)]

in (a), the amplitude would be the distance from a region of equilibrium to a center of compression or rarefaction (e.g. the left end of the spring to $x_{1}$).

However, when plotted on a sine curve (b), the $y$-axis does not represent the displacement from equilibrium. How would you, then, determine the amplitude of this wave using only the sine curve?

In other words, is it true for all types of periodic waves that their amplitude on a sine curve is measured as the distance between equilibrium and a crest (or a trough)?

Comment: The amplitude is the magnitude of the maximum displacement from the equilibrium position.

Comment: I am aware of that. What I'm asking is how you determine it using _just_ the sinusoidal representation.

Comment: Looking at the last pair of diagrams it looks like density refers to concentration of coils and if it was a sound wave in a gas that would be related to the pressure of the gas.  The connection between a displacement wave and a pressure wave is explained as an answer to this post - [Pressure variation in a sound wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499801/pressure-variation-in-a-sound-wave/499807#499807).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. When using the density diagram, is it accurate to say that we can only determine the amplitude in terms of the _density_, **not** particle displacement?

Comment: The displacement of the spring coils can be measured.  How would one measure the density?

Comment: Perhaps number of spring coils per unit length, though that isn't relevant. More specifically, let's assume I'm given _only_ the sinusoidal waveform for a longitudinal wave (whether it be a compressing/stretching spring or a sound wave), relating pressure (density, etc.) to time. Using only this information, I wouldn't be able to determine the displacement of the particles of the wave medium.

Comment: You could measure the displacement with a ruler?